# prints out the Difference (using 4-decimal places) of the maximum and minimum values

Tags: java, c, intellij-idea

I am trying to solve the problem of a **Java** program that accepts 4 real numbers from the keyboard and prints out the **Difference** (using 4-decimal places) of the maximum and minimum values of these numbers.

*Test data and expected output:
Enter four numbers: -1.5 2 7.5 11.2
Difference is 12.7000*

I have tried the following way:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class solution05 {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        double max, min;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter four numbers: ");
        double a1 = in.nextDouble();
        double a2 = in.nextDouble();
        double a3 = in.nextDouble();
        double a4 = in.nextDouble();

        if (a1 >= a2 && a1 >= a3 && a1 >= a4) {
            max = a1;
        }
        else
        if (a2 >= a1 && a2 >= a3 && a2 >= a4) {
            max = a2;
        }
        else
        if(a3 >= a1 && a3 >= a2 && a3 >= a4){
            max = a3;
        }
        else
        {
            max = a4;
        }

        if(a1 >= a2 && a1 >= a3 && a1 >= a4){
            min = a1;
        }
        else
        if(a2 >= a1 && a2 >= a3 && a2 >= a4){
            min = a2;
        }
        else
        if(a3 >= a1 && a3 >= a2 && a3 >= a4){
            min = a3;
        }
        else
        {
            min = a4;
        }
        double result = max - min;
        System.out.println("Difference is: " +result);
    }
}
```

My output is

```
Enter four numbers: 
1
5
4
9
Difference is: 0.0

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I followed the concept from a C code which serve the similar purpose.

```
#include <stdio.h>
  int main() {
    double a1, a2, a3, a4;
    double max, min;
    printf("Input four numbers: \n");
    scanf("%lf%lf%lf%lf", & a1, & a2, & a3, & a4);
    if (a1 >= a2 && a1 >= a3 && a1 >= a4)
      max = a1;
    else if (a2 >= a1 && a2 >= a3 && a2 >= a4)
      max = a2;
    else if (a3 >= a1 && a3 >= a2 && a3 >= a4)
      max = a3;
    else
      max = a4;
    if (a1 <= a2 && a1 <= a3 && a1 <= a4)
      min = a1;
    else if (a2 <= a1 && a2 <= a3 && a2 <= a4)
      min = a2;
    else if (a3 <= a1 && a3 <= a2 && a3 <= a4)
      min = a3;
    else
      min = a4;
    printf("Difference is %0.4lf\n", max - min);
    return 0;
  }
```

What am I missing here. Please help.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Why are you using nextInt() and not nextDouble()?

Comment: Thanks. Changed to nextDouble(). But output is same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you can reduce your code, then, change `nextInt()` to `nextDouble()`, then, if it doesn't work yet, try printing `max` and `min`, to check if they are assigned correctly.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class solution05 {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        double max, min;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter four numbers: ");

        double a1 = in.nextDouble();
        double a2 = in.nextDouble();
        double a3 = in.nextDouble();
        double a4 = in.nextDouble();

        max = Math.max(a1, a2);
        max = Math.max(max, a3);
        max = Math.max(max, a4);

        min = Math.min(a1, a2);
        min = Math.min(min, a3);
        min = Math.min(min, a4);

        // Print max and min here
    
        double result = max - min;
    
        String output = String.format("Difference is: %.4f", result);
        System.out.println(output);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In secons if-chain your code

```
if(a1 >= a2 && a1 >= a3 && a1 >= a4){
        min = a1;
    }
```

instead of

```
 if(a1 <= a2 && a1 <= a3 && a1 <= a4){
        min = a1;
    }
```

etc

Comment: Do I have to change all the conditions similarly?

Comment: I have got a C program of this same problem. Which works fine. Added the code in question.

Comment: Do I have to change all the conditions similarly? - Yes

Answer (score 0):

You could use Math.min and Math.max to make things easier:

```
double max = Math.max(a1, a2);
max = Math.max(max, a3);
max = Math.max(max, a4);

double min = Math.min(a1, a2);
min = Math.min(min, a3);
min = Math.min(min, a4);
```

Now simply:

```
double difference = max - mix;
```